# Подергивание при остановке CABasicAnimation

Tags: ios, objective-c

Устанавливаю анимацию следующим образом:

```
CABasicAnimation *noteAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animation];
noteAnimation.keyPath = @"position.x";
noteAnimation.byValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame) - 50];
noteAnimation.duration = 1.f;
noteAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeBoth;
noteAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
noteAnimation.autoreverses = YES;
noteAnimation.repeatCount = HUGE;
noteAnimation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear];
[self.greenSquareView.layer addAnimation:noteAnimation forKey:@"noteAnimation"];
```

Для установки на паузу действующей анимации я использую:

```
CFTimeInterval pausedTime = [view.layer convertTime:CACurrentMediaTime() fromLayer:nil];
view.layer.speed = 0.0;
view.layer.timeOffset = pausedTime;
```

Но в этом случае остановка происходит с рывком

[image: jerking]

Полный код проекта: [BitBucket](https://bacc3@bitbucket.org/bacc3/animationwithpause.git)

Comment: покажите как вы создаете анимацию.

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko добавил код создания анимации в вопрос (в комментариях не очень удачное форматирование)

Comment: поскольку у вас включен autoreverse, предположу, что она успевает показать первый кадр анимации возврата, прежде яем остановиться

Comment: В данном случае автореверс не мог на это повлиять, т.к. действие автореверса распространяется на конец анимации, в моем же случае я пытаюсь остановить действующую анимацию, т.е. ту, конец которой еще не наступил.

Comment: вынесите в отдельный проект и выложите на посмотреть

Comment: Добавил в вопрос ссылку на проект https://bacc3@bitbucket.org/bacc3/animationwithpause.git

Comment: у меня баг не воспроизводится. все отлично работает. есть какие то конкретные шаги?

Comment: У меня это стабильно воспроизводится на реальном девайсе (iphone 6, ios 10.1), в симуляторе такой проблемы нет

Comment: все равно не получается - пытался фрейм выводить сто раз в секунду, никакого прыжка нет

Comment: Я очень сомневаюсь, что это можно "увидеть" программно (выводя координаты NSLog'ом). Зато визуально это хорошо заметно. Скажите, а вот на прикрепленной к вопросу гифке вы видите обозначенную проблему?

Comment: вижу. я вам более того скажу - я гифку разложил на изображения и проверил, что это не визуальный эффект. а в чем проблема с проверкой координат?

Comment: Действительно, проверка координат - хороший ключ к пониманию возникновения проблемы. Добавил вывод координат (вывожу Х координату presentationLayer) в проект и обновил репозиторий. Но получается что координаты не меняются, а визуально меняются. Что это может означать?